# CakePHP Ajax Call to get a list for Dropdown

Tags: jquery, cakephp, getjson, cakephp-2.1, cakephp-2.2

I am trying to change a drop down based on a previously selected drop down. I am able to write the function in jQuery.

Since i am not able to use the URL path across various installation based on the server as i have to hard core the URL into the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCategory(){
    var industryId = $("#CompanyCompanyIndustryId").val();
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/gitgrow/users/fetch/'+industryId, function(data) {
        var options = '';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
          options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        $("#CompanyCompanyCategoryId").html(options);
    })
}
</script>
```

How to achieve the same using CakePHP and JS component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your javascript in the page, and use `$this->Html->url` to build your URL value.  Just  write it in `$this->Html->scriptBlock();` and add `'inline'=>false` to make it write in the head instead of at that point of the document:

```
$this->Html->scriptBlock("
    function getCategory(){
        var industryId = $(\"#CompanyCompanyIndustryId\").val();
        $.getJSON('" . $this->Html->url(array('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'fetch', $industryId)) . ", function(data) {
            var options = '';
            $.each(data, function(key, value) { 
              options += '<option value=\"' + key + '\">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            $(\"#CompanyCompanyCategoryId\").html(options);
        })
    }
", array('inline'=>false));
```

Now you have javascript that's generated in the `<head>` (or anywhere else you'd like it to be), and are using CakePHP to build the URL.

Comment: I've changed my answer to fix the quote issues I could see, but - quote issues are something you can likely fix on your own when you get into an actual editor (I wrote this in StackOverflows RTE).  The concept is the same, and I believe that's what you were asking.

Comment: got it.. i figured that out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: cant i just usethe  html url instead of using the scriptBlock. whats the advantage of using it ?

Comment: You can just use the Html helper - the benefit of the scriptBlock is that you can then tell CakePHP to put your javascript in any location on the page - in the header, or at the bottom of the page...etc.  If you're already writing where you want, you can ignore the scriptBlock part